# Linq to SQL VarChar(Max) Update is not working

Tags: c#, linq-to-sql, max, varchar

I am not able to get an update to work using Linq to SQL on a VarChar(Max) field. Here is the code I use that is called from a simple DAO class:

```
public void UpdateContentById(int ContentId, string Content) {
    CkEditorDataContext db = new CkEditorDataContext();
    CkEditorContent dbContent = db.CkEditorContents.First(c => c.CkeId == ContentId);

    dbContent.CkeContent = "This is new content";

    db.SubmitChanges();
}
```

The CkeContent field is VarChar(Max). I noticed on this question:  [LINQ to SQL Update (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1511032/linq-to-sql-update-c)
Marco seemed to have the same issue (see answer, 5th comment), but I can't tell if he ever got an answer for that particular issue.

Any help with this is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Creating a store proc for the update and calling that stored proc with Linq works fine. I'd rather not write a bunch of stored procs though. Thanks.

Comment: I've had nearly the same issue, did you ever make any progress on this?

Comment: No, unfortunately I have not found out anything more yet.

Comment: Did you try removing and readding the table in your datacontext?

Comment: I have not. I'll give it a try and let you know my results.

Comment: @Solburn What was the outcome of your remove/re-add test?

Comment: I would also try using the Linq to SQL profiler http://l2sprof.com/ , to look at the actual SQL being produced when you call SubmitChanges().

Comment: The outcome for the remove/re-add test did not work for me. This of course has been awhile now and I've stuck with the store proc since it "just works". Trying the remove/re-add test was the last thing I tried for this.

Answer (score 1):

I has the very same issue, and as far as I remember changing Property's UpdateCheck to UpdateCheck.WhenChanged will solve the problem